# How can I pass method as function parameter without 'lambda' keyword?

Tags: python

Can I somehow refer to a method without using the `lambda` keyword?

Say we have following example code:

```
class AbstractDummy:
  def size(self):
    raise NotImplementedError

class Dummy1(AbstractDummy):
  def size(self):
    return 10

class Dummy2(AbstractDummy):
  def size(self):
    return 20
```

If I have my example objects:

```
dummies1 = [Dummy1(), Dummy1(), Dummy1()]
dummies2 = [Dummy2(), Dummy2()]
```

Then if I want to `map` them, and I can do that with extracted function parameter to save me some characters:

```
f = lambda x : x.size()
map(f, dummies1)
map(f, dummies2)
```

Question here: can I somehow avoid this temporary `f` and/or `lambda` keyword?

To make a small comparison, in Java it would be possible to refer to `AbstractDummy::size` and so the invocation would look a bit like `print(map(AbstractDummy::size, dummies1)`.

Comment: If you want this to work correctly, the lambda is the simplest way here. You cannot use `AbstractDummy.size` because that will *always* call the abstract-classes `size` method (because in Python, `.size` is just a regular function here). So the lambda is a perfectly sensible solution. Alternatively, you could use `operator.methodcaller`

Comment: Though if you are only assigning the `lambda` expression to a name, just use a `def` statement.

Comment: Note, idiomatic Python almost always prefers a list comprehension/ generator expression over an equivalent `map`. Guido actually wanted to remove `map`/`filter`/`reduce` and `lambda` from Python 3! The only times I use `map` are usually reserved for mapping simple built-in functions, so `for number in map(int, user_input)` for example...

Comment: Also note, in Python, methods *only exist* when they are called from an instance. Before that, they are simply regular functions existing in some class namespace. Note, a *new method object* is created on each invocation,so `some_instance.some_method is some_instance.some_method` will be false!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `operator` module provides `methodcaller` for this.

```
from operator import methodcaller

f = methodcaller('size')

results1 = [f(x) for x in dummies1]
results2 = [f(x) for x in dummies2]
```

though `[x.size() for x in ...]` is simpler, as in C_Z_'s answer. `methodcaller` is useful for when you need a function as a function argument, for example

```
# Sort some_list_of_objects on return value of each object's `a` method.
sorted_list = sorted(some_list_of_objects, key=methodcaller('a'))
```

Answer (score 4):

In this case you would probably want to use a list comprehension

`[x.size() for x in dummies1]`

`[x.size() for x in dummies2]`